# Running a background agent with in particular period of time in a day in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to run background Agent in the windows phone using periodic task.At normal  the Background Agent or scheduled task get executed the whole day.

But i want to execute the the task from 8AM to 8PM.Is there any way to accomplish this in WP8.

If yes,help me with hints to accomplish the action.
Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0):

The only option available to you is the ScheduledAgent.

When the **OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)** method is invoked just check that the current time is within the range you are interested in (8AM to 8PM). If it is then go ahead and do your processing. If it is not just call **NotifyComplete()** and return.